# Convert SQL code to LINQ - Group By and Sum

Tags: c#, linq

can not convert to this code to LINQ and preview to data grid view.

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26742720/how-to-convert-this-query-to-linq) answer but it is not helping me

```
select tbl_user.id,tbl_user.name,tbl_user.family, sum(tbl_price.price) 
        from tbl_user,tbl_price
        where tbl_user.id=tbl_price.user_id_fk
        group by tbl_user.name+''+tbl_user.family,tbl_user.id,tbl_user.name,tbl_user.family
```

please help me to convert this code to linq

Comment: So, what are you tried to do?

Comment: Make an attempt yourself and come back with what you have tried that isn't working... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238423/linqpad-convert-sql-to-linq-command

Comment: I want each customer's purchase quantity am

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, tell what type of LINQ you're targeting (to entities?), *and* show your own first efforts. They clarify more to us than you might think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need to join the two tables, group the result by the UserId and 
call the `Sum` method on the Price property value for each items for the User.

Something like this

```
var usersWithTotalPrice = (from a in db.Users
                           join b in db.UserPrice on a.UserId equals b.UserId
                           select new { UserId = a.UserId, 
                                        FamilyName = a.Name + " " + a.FamilyName, 
                                        Price = b.Price}
                          ).GroupBy(f => f.UserId, items => items, (a, b) => new
                                     {
                                          UserId = a,
                                          FamilyName = b.FirstOrDefault().FamilyName ,
                                          Price = b.Sum(g=>g.Price)
                                     }
                          ).ToList();
```

`usersWithTotalPrice`  variable will be a collection of items each with a `UserId`, `FamilyName` and `Price` property. I used anonymous projection. If you have a view model, you can use that.

```
public class UserWithPrice
{
  public int Id { set;get;}
  public string FamilyName { set;get;}
  public decimal Price { set;get;}
}
```

and use that in the projection part

```
var usersWithTotalPrice = (from a in db.Users
                           join b in db.UserPrice on a.UserId equals b.UserId
                           select new { UserId = a.UserId, 
                                        FamilyName = a.Name + " " + a.FamilyName, 
                                        Price = b.Price}
                          ).GroupBy(f => f.UserId, items => items, (a, b) => 
                                   new UserWithPrice
                                   {
                                          Id = a,
                                          FamilyName = b.FirstOrDefault().FamilyName ,
                                          Price = b.Sum(g=>g.Price)
                                    }
                          ).ToList();
```

Update your entity/Dbset/Property names based on your definition.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to use linq for this.  Actually you can use datatable, and set the datasource of the gridview to that datatable.

```
  public void LoadData()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection("your connection string here"))
            {
                using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    conn.Open();

                    //set the command up as a select
                    cmd.CommandText = "select tbl_user.id,tbl_user.name,tbl_user.family, sum(tbl_price.price) "+
                    "from tbl_user, tbl_price " +
                    "where tbl_user.id = tbl_price.user_id_fk " +
                    "group by tbl_user.name + '' + tbl_user.family,tbl_user.id,tbl_user.name,tbl_user.family";

                    using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        a.Fill(dt);
                    }

                    //set the datasource of the gridview to the loaded table.  The gridview will now display the data of your select statement.
                    dgvActivity.DataSource = dt;

                }
            }
        }
```